# How to cast Webbrowser object to AxWebbrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have to use proxy user name and password in WebBrowser.

I have almost done just need to cast Webbrowser object into Axwebbrowser in c#.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried already?

Comment: i searched but did not get any result.

AxWebBrowser axB = (AxWebBrowser)webBrowser1; // error

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: There is no conversion, AxWebBrowser is an AxHost wrapper class that's completely unrelated to the built-in WebBrowser class.   They both wrap IE, just in different ways.  Use one or the other, don't use them both.

Comment: I have to pass proxy credential to webbrowser is there any solution without using win32 api??

Comment: How do I cast my 1999 Toyota Corrola into a 2015 Lamborghini Huracan?

Comment: @AliElegant Maybe this SO question will help: [WPF Launch Browser with Credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1237141/4265041)

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you have a control on your form, of type **WebBrowser**, that is named `webBrowser1`. You seem to want to cast this to an **AxWebBrowser** type. I don't know what **AxWebBrowser** is: it is not a class in the .NET Framework. I'm still not clear on why you want to cast it anyway.

The WinForms **WebBrowser** control is just a wrapper for an ActiveX control. You will not be able to cast **WebBrowser** directly to that ActiveX control as they are different types. However, the **WebBrowser** control does have an [**ActiveXInstance** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.activexinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns "An Object representing the underlying ActiveX WebBrowser control". This may be what you need, although your question is very vague about what you actually want to do with the ActiveX control once you get a reference to it.